# Document Library View Filters

Tags: document-library, list-view

I have a person/group field in a document library that contains multiple users.  Is there a way to set a filter in the library so that only those items that contain my name are displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the filter in the view and select the person/group field and set the value to [Me]

Comment: Wow...that was easy.  I was thinking because there were multiple people that you had to somehow use the 'contains' operator.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Modify View in the top ribbon and apply a filter on said column equal to [Me]. I used Created By below, but a person field will work also.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How are the groups broken down? Do they have a delimiter ";" between each? Are they stored as an object?

may be overkill for what you require...BUT

in jQuery there is a selector called ":contains()" - perhaps with a custom view you are able to make a ajax call to retrieve these list items and store them in a variable. Then filter this variable where your field "contains('Your name')" and append to a table.

if you wanted the current logged on user to display where there own name is, you can simply make the following ajax call:

```
let CurrentUserDisplayName

function GetCurrentUserInfo(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://**YOURSITE**/sites/**SITE**/_api/web/currentUser',
    type: 'GET',
    headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
    },
    success: function(data){
        CurrentUserDisplayName = data.Title
        console.log(CurrentUserDisplayName);
    },
    error: function(data, errorCode, errorMessage){
        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
    }
})
```

}

from this you can create a table and filter the array where the field "contains(CurrentUserDisplayName)".

Hope this helps.